# Equals result false in edited string

Tags: java, string, equals

I tried to compare 2 string  with the code:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    String xhex="31 38 30 2E 32 35 35 2E 32 32 35 2E 31 32 33";
    String hex =  remspace(xhex).trim().toString();
    System.out.println(hex);
    String hex1="3138302E3235352E3232352E313233";
    System.out.println(hex1);
    if(hex.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(hex1.trim()))
    //if (hex.equals(hex1))
      {
        System.out.println("equals");
      }else
      {
        System.out.println("not equals");
      }
}

private static String remspace(String data)
    {
      String xdata = null;
      char c='\0';
      String hex = data.replace(' ',c);
      return hex;
    }
}
```

the result  is :

```
3138302E3235352E3232352E313233
3138302E3235352E3232352E313233
not equals
```

as we can see the result is identically equals but when i tried to compare the string using equals the result is not equals. any idea why did it considered as not equals ?

Comment: There will probably be some newline or a non-printing character. Try split it to char array and compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public static String removeWhitespaces(String source){
    char[] chars = new char[source.length()];
    int numberOfNewlines = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<chars.length; i++){
        if (source.charAt(i)==' ')
            numberOfNewlines++;
        else
            chars[i-numberOfNewlines]=source.charAt(i);
    }
    return new String(chars).substring(0, source.length()-numberOfNewlines);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

They are not identical, the first string has `'\0'` in places where the space used to be. They are just displayed on the console as identical because `'\0'` is not displayed.

If you want the space to be removed use, change the `remspace` method to:

```
private static String remspace(String data) {
    return data.replace(" ", "");
}
```

Comment: is there any idea to replace the white space ? FYI I'm using STIPML so the function replace(" ","") cannot be used since the method can only read a char not a string. the snippet shows   
    The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj when i use single quotes, it shows invalid character constant error

Comment: Single quotes cannot be used, `.replace(' ', "")` nor `.replace(' ', '')` are not possible.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj `.replace(' ', '');` ? Ferry as already explained why not a few comments back.

Comment: I see... in that case OP can use replaceAll(" ", "");

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj FYI, i'm using creating a stipml application, the replaceAll(" ","") method cannot be used, it throws an error "The method replaceAll(String, String) is undefined for the type String" thats why i tried to replace the white space character using '\0'. any other idea how to replace the white space character ?

Comment: @Ferry I would like to help but I am not familiar with STIPML and more importantly with its limitations, I suggest to create a new question and precisely describe what kind of solution you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSiemion, actually STIPML is java but has a lot of limitation since it is usually used for a hardware controlling device. the question i posted here is to create a very simple text replacing to be used in STIPML app. I will create new topic/post for any further question regarding STIPML. thanks a lot for guiding me here.